# Can fields that have been inherited 2 levels deep be changed directly?

Tags: java

I am doing an edx Java course, and one of the module tasks is to write a program that makes an Employee class, that is then extended by a TechnicalEmployee, and that is extended by TechnicalLead. I construct a TechnicalLead that then gets all the fields and methods of its' parents. However, I am asked to change the salary specifically for the TechnicalLead to be 1.3 times that of what I set in TechnicalEmployee. Since we are given specific methods which we need to work with, I can't find a way to change the salary directly from TechnicalLead without adding my own custom setSalary method in the Employee class. I have also set all the fields as private.

```
public abstract class Employee {

    private String name="";
    private double salary=0;
    private static int cnt=0;
    private int id=0;


    public Employee(String name, double baseSalary){
        this.name=name;
        this.salary=baseSalary;
        this.id = ++cnt;
    }

public abstract class TechnicalEmployee extends Employee {

    private int checkins=0;

    public TechnicalEmployee(String name){
        super(name,75000);

    }

public class TechnicalLead extends  TechnicalEmployee {

    boolean Manager=true;

    public TechnicalLead(String name){
        super(name);
    }
```

There are 2 classes under TechnicalEmployee, TechnicalLead that gets a raise to 1.3 the baseSalary, and SoftwareEngineer which remains at its' initial baseSalary.  Is there a way for me to change the salary field from TechnicalLead without adding an additional setSalary method in the Employee class and without changing the field to public?

Comment: No, you cannot change it directly. That's the whole idea of access modifiers and setters in the first place. Unless you are going to use Reflection, but that's another story. `private` members are never inherited.

Comment: You could make it `protected`. Private and public are not the only options.

Comment: Or add a new Constructor to `TechnicalEmployee` which takes a salary/multiplier.

Comment: @MCEmperor I don't know what Reflection is, so I am assuming not. I just wanted to make sure I am correct in my way of thinking since I have nobody to ask on the edx website itself. If private fields aren't inherited, does that mean that TechnicalLead as an object doesn't contain them? So that basically rules out using private fields in inheritance, no?

Comment: @khelwood I will have to read a bit more on protected. Is it usually used in software development or is it shunned upon like the switch case?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I actually thought precisely of that, but since that wasn't specified in the instructions I hesitated to add it myself.

Comment: @JavaLetsGo Yes, `protected` is used. And `switch` is used. Where appropriate. I don't know what makes you think it's "shunned".

Comment: @khelwood I don't remember where I read it, either in the Oracle Certified Associate or in Head First Java that switch case wasn't as commonly used as in C++.

Comment: "not as commonly used" != "shunned"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Access Modifier]

*The table is for understanding the usage of access modifiers.

If you have your variable access modifier set as public or protected you can access the variable from child classes within the same package. If the package is different again you can not use protected to get there.

To access it from anywhere use public but do it only if necessary cause that opens the possibility of viewing and editing all values of the class from anywhere. and hence destroys the concept of hiding important data.

You can also go through the article PuProDePri in linkedIn(https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/puprodepri-ajitav-basak/) for some quick tips to remember the access modifier rule.